# Configuring Facebook with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, facebook-login

i am using this plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) for connect facebook in phonegap...
My problem is what configuring use for create the app in facebook, explaining better what plataform select for create? (Facebook Canvas, Website, iOs, Android, Windows App, Page Tab, xBox, PlayStation) ?
If i select website is necessary add a url but when use in my app phonegap he will be redirected to that right url? or not?

I appreciate the help of all ...

Answer (score 1):

You select the platform you want to create a Facebook App for. For Phonegap, this would most likely be Android and/or iOS.

Answer (score 0):

With that plugin (and other cordova plugin alternatives), you use native mobile facebook sdks, so, there are no redirections to websites. You choose android/ios platform and follow the instructions in plugin github repo readme.

It's also a good idea to skim through issues in plugin github repo and ask your questions there.